# Strawberry plants not producing fruit

Tags: fruits, strawberries

I've got quite a few strawberry plants, they're in those planters stat stack on top of each other and there's probably about 10/11 plants altogether.

Perhaps 1/3 of them have long stems with fruit growing on the end of them however the rest of them are really short with lots of leaves and no fruit on at all.

Is there anything that affects whether they are fruit-bearing or not such as Gender, growing conditions etc. ideally I'd like all of them to be fruit-bearing if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garden strawberries will stop ptoducing after they're a few years old. The runners, if rooted, will produce fruit again, though.

Bad growing conditions can also halt the fruiting process. It's possible they may have too much sun, too little water, soil that dries out too fast, or poor soil. Also, know that strawberries fruit better with a regular supply of water. If you neglect them for a while (especially in full sun), it'll show.

If they're June-bearing strawberries, they're only supposed to produce in June or so.

Alpine strawberries will fruit more consistently (without stopping after a few years), but you need to split them up, as they multiply through root division; divide them in the fall, if you have cold winters. Alpine strawberries have smaller fruits than garden strawberries.